# For-loop does not go over all objects

Tags: python, list, for-loop

Why does this for-loop not go through all items:

```
 temp = 0

 for br in my_list :
    temp +=1
    #other code here
    #my list is not used at all, only br is used inside here
    my_list.remove(br)

 print temp
 assert len(my_list) == 0 , "list should be empty"
```

So, assertion fires. Then I added the temp counter and I do see that despite my list having 202 elements, the for loop processes only 101 of them. Why is that?

Comment: Never remove from the list you are iterating! Also, why don't you just clear the list after the loop? Or use `filter` or a conditional list comprehension, depending on what you want to achieve.

Comment: use a temp list to store items you want to remove from the first one

Comment: It's also inefficient to remove items from the front of a list. Do you need to remove them inside the loop? Consider using a collections.deque

Comment: Why bother deleting *all* items from a list? You can just *stop using* the list after you're done with it.

Comment: @mkrieger1 but then you are relying on garbage collection to delete it for you if ever and when you have limited amount of memory that is not a reliable option. Also python is not known for having the best garbage collection.

Comment: If you worry about such things then Python may not be the best language to use in the first place.

Comment: @Atrotors: If you don't trust the GC to collect the list and its items when no references to it remain, why would you expect the GC to collect the list items when you remove them from the list?

Comment: @user2357112 I meant that if you leave the list alone it could linger in memory (if GC is not priority) but If you delete it from the list python removes it relatively fast because (I'm not sure about python but some GCs) pause the entire runtime and run GC, but In case removing items it could be relatively fast without pausing for too long but with an entire list it could be a lot slower and if there is an animation running that could push out of the 16ms time and animation is gonna skip a frame or two.

Comment: @Atrotors, Jython uses java's GC which can exhibit those issues. Deleting items from the head of the list is the opposite of what you need to do to make things faster. Unless you have cycles, in cpython, the objects will be removed as soon as there are no references remaining to them.

Comment: @Atrotors, the answer you've selected makes a copy of the list and then nothing is GC's until the loop is finished anyway, so it's worse, than simply deleting the list at the end. Compare the timing with `del mylist` or `mylist = []` at the end of the loop and you will see

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `for br in my_list :` with `for br in my_list[:] :`. Thanks to that you are going to iterate over a copy of the source list.

Comment: Can you please explain How does 'for br in my_list[:] :' makes a difference from 'for br in my_list :' ??

Comment: `my_list[:]` simply creates a copy of the source list. Thus, you are not modifying the source data structure. `id(my_list) != id(my_list[:])`

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't delete from the list you are iterating. Use this if you want to remove stuff

```
while list:
   item = list.pop()
   #Do stuff
```

Edit: if you want to know more about `pop()` look at the [python doc](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)

And if order is important, use `pop(0)`. `pop()` removes the last item by default and if you want to go through your list in order you should use `pop(0)` that removes the first (index 0) item and returns it.

Edit2: Thanks to user [Vincent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2846140/vincent) for the `while list` suggestion.

Comment: What about `while list:` instead?

Comment: @Vincent that could work as well but I am not sure how efficient it is.

Comment: @Vincent Thanks, I'll add that to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

tobias_k is correct removing items from a list you are iterating over causes all sorts of problems.

In this case it's relatively easy to show that it is causing the iteration to skip, by printing the list on each loop, using the repl:

```
for br in my_list:
  my_list.remove(br)
  print my_list
```

This produces:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 3, 5]
```

And finally leaves my_list containing: [1, 3, 5]

To do what you want, mic4ael is correct the simplest (although possibly not the most efficient) way is to take a copy of the list prior to iterating over it, as below:

```
my_list = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
for br in my_list[:]:     #The [:] takes a copy of my_list and iterates over it
  my_list.remove(br)
  print my_list
```

This produces:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[2, 3, 4, 5]
[3, 4, 5]
[4, 5]
[5]
[]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to reclaim the memory used by the items in the lists ASAP, you can free them like this

```
for i, br in enumerate(my_list):
    #other code here
    my_list[i] = None
```

Except in Jython where Java will free them when it feels like it